# Getting a project started in JBoss within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I've inherited a project which i'd like to test in JBoss - the problem is I cant get it to start within Eclipse. It works outside of Eclipse but I have to do a maven build, deploy the WAR files to JBoss and restart JBoss each time I make a change which is a nightmare.

In Eclipse I have added a JBoss 6 server, started it which appears to be fine (i.e. no errors in the console), then I try to run the 2 applications (one server then one client) - however nothing gets printed to the console log - no error or anything. It says started pretty much straight away. Just get a 404 error when going to the `localhost:8080/name address`.

I understand this may be difficult for someone to assist me here as there is no error message but if anyone has any suggestions or advice it would be much appreciated. I would have thought this should be simple but dont know what im doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse may be running the JBoss server so it listens to a different port.  Either that or the 8080 port is already bound so Eclipse can't open it.

Try configuring the JBoss project in Eclipse so it listens at a different port.

[Edit]
Here is a thread on jboss.org that discusses [changing the port used by JBoss when running in Eclipse](https://community.jboss.org/thread/81002?_sscc=t).

Comment: Just seems to get stuck when i do that - it never starts. What option should be selected in the deployments tab - I have 'use workspace metadata', should it be one of the others e.g. 'Use the JBoss deploy folder'?

Comment: Look at the properties of the Server project. It should set the port regardless of deployment.  In Tomcat there is an entry in the web.xml that declares which port should be used for each application, I'm assuming that JBoss has something similar.

Comment: there is nothing in either web.xml which declares the port number. Should that be in there?